# Handle keyboard interrupt, execute end block

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function that processes a list of files. I use the `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks for this:

```
begin {
    # prepate some stuff
}
process {
    # process each file
}
end {
    # clean up
}
```

Now, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, the whole script just terminates right at the spot where it was. That’s not really a problem for the process part as that will only do permanent changes on the very last command.

I do however still want to execute what’s in the `end` block to clean it up a bit, and to print some statistics about the files that did manage to get processed.

Is there a clean way to catch keyboard interrupts, while keeping the begin/process/end structure?

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this would be to disable the processing of <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> as an interupt while your script block is running.  You would have to manually check for it to break out of course but it should guarantee that the end block runs

```
begin { 
  [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
}
process {
  # Maybe check for Ctrl-C here to terminate processing
}
end { 
  [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $false
}
```

In order to check for <kbd>Ctr-C</kbd> as input in a non-blocking way you can do the following

```
if ([Console]::KeyAvailable) {
  $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
  if ($key.key -eq "C" -and $key.modifiers -eq "Control") { 
    # Clean up and exit
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Could you expand the *“maybe check for Ctrl-C here to terminate processing”* part? How can I check for Ctrl-C then inside if it’s treated as input? And how would I stop the processing without throwing an error (which would also skip the end block—or not)?

Comment: @poke i added some sample code to check for a `ctr-c` as input.  As for the end block maybe the best solution is to factor the end block processing into another function.  Then if `ctrl-c` is pressed in the `process` block you could invoke it directly and exit the loop and unconditionally invoke it via `end`

Answer (score 1):

The "finally" section of a try/catch/finally block set is still executed when the script terminates because of any of these conditions:

- Ctrl+C was pressed (at any time)
- The Exit keyword was encountered inside the catch section
- A fatal error occurred (outside the "finally" section itself)

Put all your cleanup in there.  It'll run regardless of what else happens (edit:  unless the "finally" block itself throws an error).

(further edit:  I left your original markers there for spatial reference -- they're removed now, so a literal copy/paste should not contain invalid keywords.

```
try { # begin, and/or process
}
catch { # optionally handle errors
}
finally { # clean up 
}
```

You can put your preparation steps and your actual processing all within one "try" block, or you can create two of these blocks -- either way, "try" and "catch" are required and "finally" is optional.

Comment: It would be great if that worked but it doesn’t appear to be valid syntax. I get an error that `end` is not recognized; and I don’t think `begin/process/finally` may be wrapped in anything because the use of `begin` there already throws an error causing the `catch` to be executed immediately.

Comment: Clarified the answer so it can be copy/pasted.

Comment: I know how normal exception handling works. That does not enable the ability for processing the pipe though…