# Clean session on user interupt

Tags: powershell, keyboardinterrupt

Is there a way to catch when the user interrupt the powershell script.

I need to exit a PSSession.

I have test using a try finally but the finally is not executed when the script is interupted <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>

```
try
{
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName MYCOMPUTER -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential admin )
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-EventLog -LogName Application } -Session $s
}
catch [Exception]
{

}
finally
{
    echo "Ending the session"
    Remove-PSSession $s
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708685/handle-keyboard-interrupt-execute-end-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it does not exist a script that is run when PowerShell ends. But you can have a look to [System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psengineevent_fields%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class which provides the events you can subscribe to with `Register-EngineEvent` CmdLet.

So run a PowerShell command line and execute :

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier ([System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent]::Exiting) -Action {[console]::Beep()}
```

Then close the PowerShell Command line (exit or click on the upper right corner) and you will ear something. Be carefull if the PowerShell process is killed (using task manager for example) the event is not fired.